# React JSON underline text

Tags: json, reactjs

I am using this library to display a JSON tree in react.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-json-view

How do I get a particular value say a string from the JSON tree and underline that particular value. I used a ref to access the JSON viewer and tried underlining  the particular string. Is there any other way I can underline text inside the JSON viewer. What I want is to let the user know that the string is a hyperlink.

This is my code

```
<ReactJson id="jsontree" ref={(el) => this.json = el} style={floatStyle} name="Models"
                src={this.state.table} onSelect={this.handleSelect}
                indentWidth={1}
                collapseStringsAfterLength={30}
                displayDataTypes={false} collapsed={true}
                iconStyle={"circle"} />
```

Comment: It looks that the lib does not allow to customize the rendering of components, either you ask the developer for it and wait for the implementation or fork the project and implement it yourself. It sounds like a reasonable feature

Comment: Thanks for the info. Have asked for the feature